# Get physical and virtual subdirectories of the document root in PHP

Tags: php

I have a set of Web applications, all of which are hosted in a single Apache instance:

```
/*
/
  /WebApp1
  /WebApp2
  /...
  /Common            not a Web application, just a set of utilities!
*/
```

I want to make a general home page (`/index.php`), which basically displays the list of Web applications available. So, since PHP is my server scripting language of choice, I would like to know if there is a PHP function I can use to retrieve an enumerable collection of the **physical and virtual subdirectories** of the document root.

---

Additional info: I don't know if it's necessary to specify this, but my Web applications run on Windows servers. My development machine runs Windows 7 x86 Ultimate; the test server runs Windows Server 2003; the website must also run on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [glob()](https://www.php.net/glob) on your document root directory ?

Comment: Fortunately, your solution works, as all my Web application have names that start with "Web". :)

Comment: However, just note that you don't have to use `glob()` with a prefix or suffix. You can do `$array = glob("*")` and it will return all files and directories for current working directory.
Glad it worked for you anyway :)